# Calling a Macro as Argument of Another Macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, arguments

How can I call a macro in an argument of another macro? I am having difficulty running the following `LaTeX` code. I used `\fpeval` to be able to process floating-point numbers.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xfp}
\newcommand{\singleBox}[4]
{
    \fill(\fpeval{#1}mm,\fpeval{#2}mm) rectangle (\fpeval{#1} mm + \fpeval{#3} mm,\fpeval{#2} mm - \fpeval{#4} mm);
}

\newcommand{\subtractOne}[1]{
    \number\numexpr#1-1\relax%
}

\newcommand{\convertNum}[5] 
{
    \def\offsetOne{\fpeval{\subtractOne{#1}}}
    \def\offsetTwo{\fpeval{\subtractOne{#2}}}
    \ifnum #1<6
        \fpeval{#3 + 9 + (#4 + #5)*\offsetOne + \offsetTwo}
    \else
        % to be completed...
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw=black] (0mm,0mm) rectangle (300 mm, 400 mm);
    \singleBox{100}{200}{24}{13} % This works just fine
    \singleBox{\convertNum{1}{1}{0}{2}{1.46}}{200}{24}{13}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error messages:

```
Undefined control sequence. ...convertNum{1}{1}{0}{2}{1.46}}{200}{24}{13}
You can't use `\def' after \the. ...convertNum{1}{1}{0}{2}{1.46}}{200}{24}{13}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have unexpandable instructions such as `\def` in that macro. But you can simply subtract 1 in the expression.

You can even do better:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xfp}

\newcommand{\singleBox}[4]{%
  \fill(\fpeval{#1}mm,\fpeval{#2}mm) rectangle
    (\fpeval{#1} mm + \fpeval{#3} mm,\fpeval{#2} mm - \fpeval{#4} mm);
}

\newcommand{\convertNum}[5]{%
  \fpeval{#1<6 ? #3 + 9 + (#4 + #5)*(#1-1) + (#2-1) : 0}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[draw=black] (0mm,0mm) rectangle (300 mm, 400 mm);
  \singleBox{100}{200}{24}{13} % This works just fine
  \singleBox{\convertNum{1}{1}{0}{2}{1.46}}{200}{24}{13}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\fpeval` accepts expressions of the form

```
<fp expression><comparator><fp expression> ? <fp expression> : <fp expression>
```

The comparator can be `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` or `!=`; the expression after `?` is used if the comparison returns true, the expression after `:` when the comparison returns false.

In the code I left `0` for the false branch.

Comment: Can I have nothing in the false branch? The reason I am asking is that I need to have multiple if statements in `\convertNum` macro, i.e., condition#1: `\fpeval{#1<6 ? #3 + 9 + (#4 + #5)*(#1-1) + (#2-1) : NULL}`, condition#2: `\fpeval{#1>7 && #1<20 ? #3 + 9 + (#4 + #5)*(#1-1)*2 + (#2-1) : NULL}`.